# Getting a value of a specific key

Tags: arrays, json, go, key-value

I'm a getting a string like this from database.

> [{"Key":"a","Value":"4521"},{"Key":"b","Value":"7"}]

I want to get the value of the key "b" . What is the optimal way to do that in Go?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you just trying to parse that string as JSON? If not, can you post how you're accessing your database?

Comment: @kingkupps I'm just trying to parse the string and access the value of the key "b"

Comment: @Hash934 this looks like a **json** string, Are you sure all strings you will gate will have exactly *same format*?

Comment: yes @OlegButuzov . All are in the same format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    str := `[{"Key":"a","Value":"4521"},{"Key":"b","Value":"7"}]`

    // declaring out struct we will use for unmarshaling and iteration check.
    out := []struct {
        Key, Value string
    }{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &out); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        // searching for value.
        for i := range out {
            if out[i].Key == "b" {
                fmt.Println("Found", out[i].Value)
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is an easy way to do that, not optimal. Optimal wound be parse string manually, byte by byte.

Comment: Oleg, This Works fine . Thanks a lot